# Determine age of timing belt on a 2003 Honda Accord before purchase

Tags: honda, accord, timing-belt

The belt which I can see when I open the car bonnet seems to be new, but my friend says that is not the timing belt and it can not be seen from outside. The car is a Honda accord 2003 V6 which I am planning to buy, with 99K miles. The dealer says he has no idea if the belt was replaced. Is there any way to check if the timing belt has been replaced?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a picture of what I believe your engine should look like:

[image]

The red arrow should be what you are seeing. This is the serpentine belt which drives the accessories. The green arrow is the cover which inside is where the timing belt lies. There is no real way to tell if the timing belt has been changed. After a couple hundred miles of running on the engine, it no longer looks fresh, so you couldn't really even tell by pulling the cover. As I'm sure you've been told, in most cars the timing belt should be changed at 60k miles.

With any engine you are unsure of which does not have a complete maintenance history, changing out the timing belt is the first thing I'd do. If you don't and it breaks because it hasn't been changed on time, you'll then have a very expensive paper weight (in most cases). If you are buying 99k mile car without the maintenance history, change the timing belt right off. Better to be safe then sorry.

Comment: thanks for helping me with the image Paul... I will follow your advice

Comment: The first thing I do when I buy a second hand car with a sketchy service history is change the timing belt.  A few hundred $/£ for peace of mind and the potential saving of thousands.

Comment: Agreed, I've changed quite a few of those belts. They basically look used after a couple hundred miles. That timing cover is also VERY difficult to get to anyway.

Comment: You can tell when it's REALLY time to change the belt, though. Which could give indication on how well the car has been taken care of.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing - The only *sure* way you can tell is when the belt brakes or slips ... by then it's too late. Maybe that's what you're getting at.

Comment: As @Paulster2 noted, in some cases a timing belt breaking will not break your engine. Timing belt failures will result in bent valves in an "interference" engine, but not in a "non-interference" engine (the 7a-fe engine in my 1996 corolla is an example). If you're shopping around for more than just a honda accord, you may want to research whether the engine you're buying is interference or not. Timing belts will break eventually on all cars, but a non-interference engine could mean the difference between the mechanic and the junkyard.

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 well if the belt slips then it's really too late. But it usually starts cracking and splitting much before that, also develops a "glazed" appearance.